# An error occurred: Requesed falied with status code 404 in a search bar

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, client, http-status-code-404, searchbar

I have a problem with my search bar
Eavrytime I enter the page with the search bar I get 404 error:

> An error occurred: Requesed falied with status code 404

And in the terminal I get this massage:

> GET /api/photos/photo/undefined 404 0.830 ms

And the search bar doesn't work

This is my url:

```
import http from "./httpService";

 export const getPhoto = (photoId) =>
 http.get(`http://localhost:8181/api/photos/${photoId}`);
```

This is the page with the search bar:

```
import PageHeader from "../components/PageHeader";
import Search from "../components/SearchBar";
import { getPhoto } from "../services/photoService";
import React from "react";
import "../css/Gallery and galleryDetails.css";
import PhotoExtends from "../components/Photos/PhotoExtends";

class Gallery extends PhotoExtends {
  state = {
    data: [],
    photos: [],
    isMount: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const { data } = await getPhoto();
      this.setState({ data, isMount: true, photos: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <PageHeader title="גלריה" subTitle="והנה כמה מהדברים שלנו" />
        <div>
          <Search handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="hoverPics">
            <a href="donatsDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/donats.png"
                alt="donats"
                title="סופגניות"
                description="סופגניות עבור חנוכה בלבד"
                description2="סופגניות עבור חנוכה בלבד"
                photoId="6316242e8364d16b288cf017"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="alphaphoresDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/alphaphores.png"
                alt="alphaphores"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="simbaDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/simba.png"
                alt="simba"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="heartCakeDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/heart cake.png"
                alt="heart cake"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="puffsDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/puffs.png"
                alt="puffs"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="ofirCakeDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/ofir cake.png"
                alt="ofir cake"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="macaroonsDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/macaroon.png"
                alt="macaroons"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="whiteCakeDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/white cake.png"
                alt="whiteCake"
              />
            </a>
            <a href="redCakeDetails">
              <img
                className="gallery"
                src="/assets/images/red cake.png"
                alt="redcake"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

This is the code of the search bar:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

const SearchBar = ({ handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="field">
      <input
        type="search"
        className="text-rtl form-control"
        placeholder="חפש מוצר"
        onInput={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

SearchBar.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Photo Extends:

```
import { Component } from "react";

class PhotoExtends extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    let photos = data;
    const searchTerm = e.target.value;
    const photosFiltered = photos.filter((photo) => {
      return (
        photo.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
        photo.bizNumber.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    this.setState({ photos: photosFiltered });
  };
}

export default PhotoExtends;
```

Cuz that I gusse the problem is in client side all the codes from there but if you think the problem form server side I'll glad to know.

All the data of the photos save in a file in mongoDB ubder the name photos and that's where the URL should lead
(Right now I have data of only 1 pic for the exmaple, the pic with the alt donats)

I'd to be glad to understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

The `getPhoto` function expects to be passed a `photoId` argument, but when it is called from `componentDidMount`, it is not passed any arguments, which results in calling `http.get('http://localhost:8181/api/photos/undefined')`, which appears to be returning HTTP status 404.